# What is this algorithm called and what is the time complexity?

Tags: algorithm

Let's call the amount of RAM available R.

We have an unsorted file of 10 gigs with one column of keys (duplicates allowed).

You split the file into k files, each of which have size R.
You sort each file and write the file to disk.

You read (10 / R) gigs from each file into input buffers. You perform a k-way merge where you read the first key from the first file and compare to every other key in your input buffers to find the minimum. You add this to your output buffer which should also hold (10 / R) gigs of data.

Once the output buffer is full, write it to disk to a final sorted file.

Repeat this process until all k files have been fully read. If an input buffer is empty, fill it with the next (10 / R) gigs of its corresponding file until the file has been entirely read. We can do this buffer refilling in parallel.

What is the official name for this algorithm? Is it a K - Way Merge sort?

The first part, where we split into K files is O((n / k) log (n / k))
The second part, where we merge is O(nk)?

If I am wrong, can I have an explanation? If this is external merge sort, how do we optimize this further?

Comment: How are you sorting each of the k files?

Comment: @hatchet it isn't relevant to the question, those files each fit into memory. You can use any handy sorting algorithm, particularly one built into your language library of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a textbook [external merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting#External_merge_sort) Time complexity O(n log n)

Here's Wikipedia's entry on it (linked above):

> One example of external sorting is the external merge sort algorithm,
>   which sorts chunks that each fit in RAM, then merges the sorted chunks
>   together. For example, for sorting 900 megabytes of data using
>   only 100 megabytes of RAM: 
>     1) Read 100 MB of the data in main memory and
>   sort by some conventional method, like quicksort. 
>     2) Write the sorted
>   data to disk. 
>     3) Repeat steps 1 and 2 until all of the data is in sorted
>   100 MB chunks (there are 900MB / 100MB = 9 chunks), which now need to
>   be merged into one single output file. 
>     4) Read the first 10 MB (= 100MB /
>   (9 chunks + 1)) of each sorted chunk into input buffers in main memory
>   and allocate the remaining 10 MB for an output buffer. (In practice,
>   it might provide better performance to make the output buffer larger
>   and the input buffers slightly smaller.) 
>     5) Perform a 9-way merge and
>   store the result in the output buffer. Whenever the output buffer
>   fills, write it to the final sorted file and empty it. Whenever any of
>   the 9 input buffers empties, fill it with the next 10 MB of its
>   associated 100 MB sorted chunk until no more data from the chunk is
>   available. This is the key step that makes external merge sort work
>   externally -- because the merge algorithm only makes one pass
>   sequentially through each of the chunks, each chunk does not have to
>   be loaded completely; rather, sequential parts of the chunk can be
>   loaded as needed.
>  Historically, instead of a sort, sometimes a
>   replacement-selection algorithm was used to perform the initial
>   distribution, to produce on average half as many output chunks of
>   double the length.

Comment: Is an external merge sort really O(nlogn)? Don't you have to take into consideration the size of chunks as a different variable?

Comment: Also, Is this an external merge sort?  A standard merge sort splits the data down into sorted chunks and then merges them back up The algorithm in the question splits the file into chunks, sorts them and then reads from all files as much as it can and performs a k- way merge. It's not really merging back up in chunks

Comment: The size of the chunks is ultimately N. You split the file into N/R chunks, and sort them individually in O(N/R log N/R) time. Then you merge the R chunks together in an operation that would likely use a priority queue (read: heap) for a k-way merge. The queue will effectively sort in O(N log N) time as you repeatedly pull off the smallest element for an overall complexity of O(N log N)

Comment: Splitting into a file and then merging those files is just a variation on the theme; it's ultimately the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's [a merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm), exact file IO is an implementation detail.